# DOM W3c XML Element Parsing Null Attribute

Tags: java, xml, dom, nullpointerexception

I am parsing some data from XML using DOM in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FEFExchangeFile>
    <program>
        <identProgram name="TestSection" type="section" task="MAST"></identProgram>
        <FBDSource nbRows="24" nbColumns="36">
```

The node list of "program" node parses correctly like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(CodeFile);
NodeList programeNodeList= doc.getElementsByTagName("program");
```

I get the "program" element in for loop from the nodelist which also works fineas below:

```
 // Get the current program node element
 Element programNode = (Element) programeNodeList.item(i);
```

Then when I get to get the first item "identProgram" in the "program" element it works fine like this and I can pick up the attributes into a string:

```
 // Get the IdentProgram node element from Program node
 Element identProgramElement = (Element) programNode.getElementsByTagName("identProgram").item(0);
```

But what has got me stumped. In the exact same code as above that I use for getting the "identProgram" I use to get the next item after that "fbdSource" but it is giving me a null pointer exception:

```
 // Get the FbdSource element from Program node 
 Element fBDSourceElement = (Element) programNode.getElementsByTagName("FBDSource").item(0);
```

As stated the code used to get the identProgram and the fbdSource are the same. They are at the same level in the xml. Not sure what would cause this.

Thanks

Comment: The first step is to determine which reference is `null`. Unfortunately, we won't be able to be much help without a [mcve] and the full error (stack trace).

Comment: please provide the xml content and error clearly